# Windows Server - Can't visit a local website

Tags: iis-7, windows-server-2003

I have a few websites running on my server (Windows Server 2003 R2), and they all work just fine for people visiting sites etc. However, when I am logged onto the machine via RDP, I cannot visit a webiste using it's url.

I just get `Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage`.

I thought it might be hosts file thing, but it looks fine to me, just has:

```
 127.0.0.1       localhost
```

Comment: Can you access it using http:\\localhost or http:\\127.0.0.1?
ie., Is it the domain name that is causing the problem?

Comment: It's the fact that it's the IP of the server. I suppose it has to loop back to itself and gets confused somewhere.